# Showing $(M^M, \circ )$ is a monoid.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, monoid

Show that group $(M^{M},\circ)$ is a monoid with a neutral element $id_{M}$.

$id_{M}$ is defined as "identity mapping" (closest translation that I could have gotten)
$id_{M}: M \rightarrow M, x \mapsto x$, where $M$ is a set and $x$ is an element of a set.

I'm not sure how can I start, especially that I don't really know what set $M^M$ is defined as.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $M^M$ could mean mappings from $M$ to $M$ (the power set $2^M$ can be identified with the set of all functions from $M$ to a set of two elements)

Comment: Hi! I was thinking that its has an interpretation in the direction of the power set $2^M$

Comment: @HoaL So for sets $A$ and $B$, it is standard to denote $B^A$ as the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$.  This is because if $|A|=a$ and $|B|=b$, then $|B^A|=b^a$ by a simple counting argument.  That being said, when trying to understand how to prove something, you must first make sure to understand what the problem is saying, so it is good that you pointed out your need for clarity on the notation $M^M$.

Comment: thanks guys, yep i mostly had problems with the notation $M^M$. its all clear now and the problem became quite trivial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A^B$ is standard notation for the set of functions with domain $B$ and codomain $A$. Therefore your structure is the set of functions with domain $M$ and codomain$ M$ endowed with the operation of composition of functions.

As for where to start, you really only have the two things to check, which you should be able to do without too much trouble.

Comment: thanks! yeah now everything makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Well, the operation is composition. The composition of mappings $f,g\in M^M$ is a mapping $f\circ g\in M^M$. So the operation $\circ : M^M\times M^M\rightarrow M^M:(f,g)\mapsto f\circ g$ is well-defined.

This operation is associative, i.e., for all $f,g,h\in M^M$, $(f\circ g)\circ h = f\circ (g\circ h)$.

Finally, $id_M$ is the identity element, i.e., for all $f\in M^M$, $f\circ id_M = f = id_M\circ f$.